# Excel is referencing another version of my file. How can I make it reference itself instead?

Tags: excel

I imported tabs from one version of my file to another and now, instead of showing a simple:

```
VLOOKUP(A1, B:C, 2, FALSE)
```

It is showing

```
VLOOKUP('C:\users\desktop\[report v0.2]K1'!A1, B:C, 2, FALSE)
```

How do I remove this referencing and make my file reference itself? I have a K1 tab in the file I'm working on. Why would it be referencing another file...
I would not mind changing it for a few cells, but I have millions of cells to change.

Thank you.

Comment: Can you just do a `Find/Replace` of Formulas for `'C:\users\desktop\[report v0.2]K1'!` and replace with `'K1'!`?

Comment: ...yeah that's what I did. Thank you.